# Bluetooth speaker connected but output sound still coming out on laptop Windows 11

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11, speakers

I have a JBL charge essential bluetooth speaker, I can pair them & see that the windows & speaker are paired but I can't find the JBL speaker for output sound list in which my other bluetooth headset just like the airpods are seen. I'm really desperate to fix this one hoping someone will able to help. I tried delete & pair them again but still it doesn't work.

Comment: CAPSLOCK STUCK TOO

Comment: Using the brainless process of elimination method.. does this speaker work fine with other systems?  Can your iPhone drive it?  Can an android phone also drive it?  Figuring out if the problem is the speaker or PC is your first step.

Comment: yes it's working fine with phones. It's just the output sound of my laptop is still coming out to laptop even though bluetooth speaker is connected.